# How to install RRD PHP extension on OS X

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, rrdtool, rrd

I need the support of RRDTool http://php.net/manual/en/ref.rrd.php in my php installation. I'm used to install php extensions using Homebrew. However, this time for RRD there isn't any available.

How can I install this extension so I can use functions like `rrd_fetch()` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone was strugling with the same, install it using `pecl`

`pecl install rrd`

You need to have php installation with PEAR: `brew install php71 --with-pear`.

Also, don't forget to see PEAR config notes after php installation or using `brew info php71`:

> ✩✩✩✩ PEAR ✩✩✩✩
>
> If PEAR complains about permissions, 'fix' the default PEAR
>   permissions and config:
>
> ```
> chmod -R ug+w /usr/local/opt/php71/lib/php
> pear config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini system
> ```